# How to combine two sql counts from same joined table

Tags: mysql

another annoying student here!
Today I spend hours trying to combine (select) 2 already joined SQL outputs + the ID of the original table in a single table output. which ultimately resulted in this query:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT fd1.User_idUser,avg(fd1.caloryIntake) 
AS 'workdays'
FROM fact_dailysnapshot fd1
INNER JOIN dim_day dd1 ON dd1.DATE_SK = fd1.DATE_SK
WHERE dd1.weekend_ind = 'N'
GROUP BY fd1.User_idUser 
ORDER BY fd1.User_idUser) A,

(SELECT avg(fd1.caloryIntake) AS 'weekend'
FROM fact_dailysnapshot fd1
INNER 
JOIN dim_day dd1 ON dd1.DATE_SK = fd1.DATE_SK
WHERE dd1.weekend_ind = 'Y'
GROUP BY fd1.User_idUser 
ORDER BY fd1.User_idUser) B;
```

Which translates into…
[image: output]

Now this is a false result, the second column gives an almost constant value for all user entries. I think this must be solved with some kind of EXTRA join but I literally ran out of ideas. Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JOIN` is missing an `ON` clause to relate d`User_idUser`.

But, the simplest way to write the query uses conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT fd1.User_idUser,
       avg(case when dd1.weekend_ind = 'N' then fd1.caloryIntake end) as weekday_avg,
       avg(case when dd1.weekend_ind = 'Y' then fd1.caloryIntake end) as weekend_avg
FROM fact_dailysnapshot fd1 INNER JOIN
     dim_day dd1
     ON dd1.DATE_SK = fd1.DATE_SK
GROUP BY fd1.User_idUser 
ORDER BY fd1.User_idUser;
```

This is one query instead of two.

Comment: I never used conditional aggregation, but it certainly simplifies everything.
Do note that the first answer runs 100ms faster.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT A.User_idUser, A.workdays, B.weekend 

FROM (

    SELECT fd1.User_idUser, avg(fd1.caloryIntake) AS 'workdays'
    FROM fact_dailysnapshot fd1
    INNER JOIN dim_day dd1 
       ON dd1.DATE_SK = fd1.DATE_SK
    WHERE dd1.weekend_ind = 'N'
    GROUP BY fd1.User_idUser 
    ORDER BY fd1.User_idUser) A

JOIN 
    (SELECT fd1.User_idUser, avg(fd1.caloryIntake) AS 'weekend'
    FROM fact_dailysnapshot fd1
    INNER JOIN dim_day dd1 
       ON dd1.DATE_SK = fd1.DATE_SK
    WHERE dd1.weekend_ind = 'Y'
    GROUP BY fd1.User_idUser 
    ORDER BY fd1.User_idUser) B

    ON A.User_idUser = B.User_idUser
```

Each query gives you all users by ID and their workdays or weekends. You need to JOIN the results of the two query on the user ID.

Comment: @NicolasMassart - see Gordon's answer. It is better than mine :) He simplified it to a single query. Understanding what he did is good learning ;)